# How to display (Google) Maps on .Net Maui

Tags: .net, dictionary, maui

I'm playing around with .Net Maui. I'd like to add a map to my demo app. Unfortunately it seems that the map control has not been migrated yet. Also it seems that the promised implementation of the control has been removed from the roadmap for RC.

Also existing projects like this one: https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps
doesn't support .Net Maui...

Does anybody already include a map to a .Net Maui project and could give me some a hint?

Thx!

Answer (score 7):

To use Google or Apple Maps in .NET MAUI, while it is not yet in the Framework , make use of your own handler. You can find a [detailed blog post on our website](https://www.cayas.de/blog/dotnet-maui-custom-map-handler?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=local&utm_campaign=sof).

But in general, you have to do the following steps:

1. Create a view that represents your map

```cs
    public class MapView : View, IMapView
    { }
```

This is the control you use inside your ContentPage.

2. Create the platform-independent handler-implementation to render your view

To render your view, MAUI needs a platform-independent entry point.

```cs
    partial class MapHandler
    {
        public static IPropertyMapper<MapView, MapHandler> MapMapper = new PropertyMapper<MapView, MapHandler>(ViewMapper)
        { };

        public MapHandler() : base(MapMapper)
        { }
    }
```

That needs to be registered in your MauiProgram.cs

```cs
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
{
    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(MapHandlerDemo.Maps.Map),typeof(MapHandler));
})
```

3. Create the platform-specific handler-implementation

A handler tells MAUI how to render your control. So you need a handler for each platform you want to support.
The iOS handler is, in comparison to Android, simpler and shorter to implement.

```cs
    public partial class MapHandler : ViewHandler<MapView, MKMapView>
    {
        public MapHandler(IPropertyMapper mapper, CommandMapper commandMapper = null) : base(mapper, commandMapper)
        { }

        protected override MKMapView CreatePlatformView()
        {
            return new MKMapView(CoreGraphics.CGRect.Empty);
        }

        protected override void ConnectHandler(MKMapView PlatformView)
        { }

        protected override void DisconnectHandler(MKMapView PlatformView)
        {
            // Clean-up the native view to reduce memory leaks and memory usage
            if (PlatformView.Delegate != null)
            {
                PlatformView.Delegate.Dispose();
                PlatformView.Delegate = null;
            }

            PlatformView.RemoveFromSuperview();
        }
    }
```

Next step would be to implement your Android handler.

Comment: And Android is the problem ... look at your screenshot at your blog, the Android simulator map-screen is simply empty, no map at all. After a few days testing, double checking the google api keys, looking around the Xamarin source, looking at the logcat output. I gave up, with an empty screen instead a map. Did it really work with Android ?

Comment: @Freudi, teqila slammer's  blogpost misses one thing on Android: calling OnResume() on map view. This is what prevents it from loading. This how should CallCreateMap method should look like:

    public void CallCreateMap()
    {
        _mapView.OnCreate(_bundle);
        _mapView.OnResume();
        _mapView.GetMapAsync(this);
    }

If you still have trouble loading map, than I would suggest checking MSDN guide for using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps nuget: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api

Comment: Wow, Thanks Mantas, only 1 line of code and I tried so many other things. Thanks now it works ! I will try to tell it Giulien from Cayas that he may update his blog.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We fixed it in the blog post.

Answer (score 3):

I also missing it. In an earlier roadmap of the MAUI team it was announced for February/2022 and MAUI Version 12, but meanwhile we have end of March and MAUI 14, but no progress in the map control.
But Xamarin, the predecessor, still have it. Btw. that prevents me to move to MAUI.

Answer (score 2):

With .net 7.0 there has been added the control [Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps/)

Documentation: [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0)

Simple demo Maui app: [MapDemo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/Map/MapDemo)

Answer (score 1):

Try the GoogleApi package by Michael Vivet on NuGet. It is compatible with Net5. I have downloaded the source and added Net6 to the dll, it works perfectly.

Comment: Correct me if I a wrong, but if I remember correctly GoogleApi nuget can only load static maps, meaning map will not be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

i have ported Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps to .NET MAUI. Feel free to contact me if u have any issues: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Onion.Maui.GoogleMaps/

Comment: this is a nice plugin, thanks for your effort. However the iOS app crashes at splash screen if you are deploying the app on older iOS devices such as 12.5, but it is working fine in iOS 17.

Comment: @ArjunKR if i recall correctly, the minimum supported ios version for the latest ios maps sdk is ios 13, hence this is not the plugin's problem. If u launch a native app i doubt you will get different results

Answer (score 0):

From .net7.0 you can use Map controls.

More info about this you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0).

I created last week my own topic about it for databinding. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742589/binding-location-to-net-maui-map/75751676?noredirect=1#comment133653273_75751676).

Answer (score -2):

Try like this please:

```
<WebView Source="https://embed.windy.com" />
```

[Check please also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with WebView but ideally the solution should support placing markers by the user on the map.

I also already take a look at the Google Maps API! But I was hoping to find a solution which I can use in Android and iOS. As far as I know Google Maps API only works on Android.