# How to display an interactive map on a page of a .NET 6 Blazor Hybrid application?

Tags: google-maps, blazor, blazor-hybrid

It looks like [cross-platform maps for .NET 7 MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkEWltr6Aq0) are built in, but is there any way to get maps working on .NET 6?

I know I can use the [`IMap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/maps?view=net-maui-6.0&tabs=windows) and [`IGeolocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/geolocation?view=net-maui-6.0&tabs=windows) interfaces to open the device's maps application with some relevant coordinates, or calculate distances between locations, but I'd like to display a map directly on the page. I'd also want to interact with features such as adding pins and geofences. I've looked around but I'm unable to find a solution.

Comment: May have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72379499/12300287).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found was [GeoBlazor](https://www.geoblazor.com/). It is an open-source package that displays a map with many functionalities. Unfortunately, it requires a subscription to [ArcGIS API](https://developers.arcgis.com/pricing/), which you have to pay for if your usage goes outside their free tier.

However, I realized something that should have been obvious - as long as there is an API, I can use any service, such as [Google maps](https://mapsplatform.google.com/), across all the platforms.

Thankfully, a third-party service won't be necessary anymore as .NET MAUI will have [cross-platform maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkEWltr6Aq0) built in starting from .NET 7.